# Invalid type "string | undefined" of template literal expression in React/TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm testing whether a POST method is being called upon submission:

```
process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/';


it('should make a POST request when called', async () => {
    await contactProxy(defaultRequest, response);

    expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        //underlined with a warning
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}tenants/v1/${locale}/inquiries`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: getDefaultHeaders(),
            body: JSON.stringify(defaultRequest.body)
        }
    );
});
```

but `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL` is underlined with `Invalid type "string | undefined" of template literal expression in React/TypeScript`

Casting

`process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/' as string;`

doesn't solve it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding not null assertion to env variable, like so:

```
${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL!}tenants/v1/${locale}/inquiries
```

Answer (score -1):

The environments from `process.env` are all defined as `string | undefined`.

In order to fix this, you have to extract the environment in a variable and type check on it

```
process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/';


it('should make a POST request when called', async () => {
    await contactProxy(defaultRequest, response);

    const NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL;

    if(NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL) {
      expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        `${NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}tenants/v1/${locale}/inquiries`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: getDefaultHeaders(),
            body: JSON.stringify(defaultRequest.body)
        }
      );
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest doing NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL===undefined rather than this. There might be cases where falsy values are valid, but won't go through this.